# xpath node extraction base

Tags: xml, arrays, xpath

How can can I extract image `sourceURL` for image whose height is 400? Below is xml output:

```
<imageList>
    <image available="true" height="100" width="100">
        <sourceURL>di/35/4b/49/5a5846562d77473973776e566b737757387877-100x100-0-0.jpg?rqid=p12.2aef1330047882eacc81&rqt=SRS&a=1&c=44&l=8079962&r=1&pr=1&lks=78809.4&fks=69208</sourceURL>
    </image>
    <image available="true" height="200" width="200">
        <sourceURL>images/di/35/4b/49/5a5846562d77473973776e566b737757387877-200x200-0-0.jpg?rqid=p12.2aef1330047882eacc81&rqt=SRS&a=1&c=44&l=8079962&r=1&pr=1&lks=78809.4&fks=69208</sourceURL>
    </image>
    <image available="false" height="300" width="300">
        <sourceURL>sc/ds/no_image_100X100.jpg?rqid=p12.2aef1330047882eacc81&rqt=SRS&a=1&c=44&l=8079962&r=1&pr=1&lks=78809.4&fks=69208</sourceURL>
    </image>
    <image available="false" height="400" width="400">
        <sourceURL>sc/ds/no_image_100X100.jpg?rqid=p12.2aef1330047882eacc81&rqt=SRS&a=1&c=44&l=8079962&r=1&pr=1&lks=78809.4&fks=69208</sourceURL>
    </image>
    <image available="true" height="215" width="200">
        <sourceURL>http://di67.shoppingshadow.com/images/di/35/4b/49/5a5846562d77473973776e566b737757387877-200x215-0-0.jpg?rqid=p12.2aef1330047882eacc81&rqt=SRS&a=1&c=44&l=8079962&r=1&pr=1&lks=78809.4&fks=69208</sourceURL>
    </image>
</imageList>
```

Answer (score 1):

`/imageList/image[@height < 400]/sourceURL`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a predicate on the `image` step in the path, e.g.

```
/imageList/image[@height = 400]/sourceURL
```